# REST API document generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

Is there a library that provides a markup for writing REST API documentation? I have seen several companies use similar documentation pattern, e.g:

http://api.teamlab.com/2.0/

http://www.fullcontact.com/docs/?category=person

I am wondering if they are using the same library or service. Essentially, the library should generate pages for API navigation, search and display ( much like YARD for ruby documentation)  based on the markup text.

This is what I have found so far:

- [rapi_doc gem](https://github.com/elc/rapi_doc). Here is an [article](http://www.rubyglob.com/generating-api-documentation-with-rapi_doc/) discussing the usage.

Comment: Check out http://developer.mashery.com/iodocs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should definitely have a look at [**Swagger**](http://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/).

It is Open Source, used by hundreds of APIs and also used by 3scale in its API Management solution under the name Active Docs.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [IO/Docs](http://mashery.com/solution/iodocs) from Mashery.

> Mashery I/O Docs, the next generation of API documentation and exploration, let developers execute live API calls directly from your docs. Think docs meet testing and debugging, all in one convenient, interactive interface.

Check out the [Parse API Docs](https://parse.com/docs/rest) for another example of great docs.

Also, we spent a lot of time designing the [FullContact API Docs](http://www.fullcontact.com/docs/). We make use of the [Apigee Live API Console](http://apigee.com/node/187) as well.

Comment: did you guys build a gem to generate the docs or did you use the Mashery generated pages as a basis for your documentation. BTW, great job on the docs front!

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful gem for api documentaion (Rails4 and Rails5)

ApiDoco https://rubygems.org/gems/apidoco/versions/1.2.0.

It is very easy to setup and have a good user experience.

Comment: Kindly add answer here also. As external link might change in future